# Customize Pagination create_links() in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, pagination

```
<?php foreach(range('A', 'Z')as $key=>$letter)
      {
        echo anchor('KitchenGuruAdminController/Admin_recipe_browse/'.$letter, ' '.$letter);
      }
      echo "<BR><BR>";
 ?>

<table  cellpadding='5'>
<th>Delete</th>
<th></th>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Recipe name</th>
<th>Edit</th>

<?php if(isset($records)) : foreach($records as $recipe) : ?>   
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="idsToDelete[]" value="<?=$recipe['recipeid']?>" /><td>
        <td><?php echo $recipe['recipeid'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $recipe['recipename'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo anchor('KitchenGuruAdminController/Admin_recipe_edit/'.$recipe['recipeid'], 'Click'); ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        <tr><?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?></tr>
<?php else : ?>
<h5>Recipe Database Empty.</h5>
<?php endif; ?>
</table>
</br></br><input type="submit" name="delete_button" onclick="delete_alert()"value="Delete"/>
<?php form_close(); ?>
```

The above code is my view, nevermind the button and checkboxes, they are for deletion of rows.

I have successfully paginated my results. and created links from A-Z and send the corresponding letter as a segment.

Here is my controller for pagination browse:

```
function Admin_recipe_browse()
    {
        $character = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'index.php/KitchenGuruAdminController/Admin_recipe_browse';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->KitchenGuruAdminModel->browse_total_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['records'] = $this->KitchenGuruAdminModel->get_records($character,$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        //$data['records'] = $this->KitchenGuruAdminModel->get_records($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('Admin_recipe_browse', $data);
    }
```

The  code works fine, if i click A. it will only show results with A as the first character. The problem is when i click on the pagination links. It replaces the uri segment of my letter to a number(`$config['per_page'];`)

so when i go back to page 1 on my pagination links, it will not filter the results for the character link.

sample,

> /segment1/segment2/A

this is my url after i click the links i made using foreach range.

my pagination is set to only show 5 per page, so when i click on page 2. the url becomes.

> /segment1/segment2/5

Back to my question, i have thought of a solution, set my Character filter as segment(3) and the per_page as segment(4).

problem is i don't know how to customize `$this->pagination->create_links();`

Currently reading pagination class documentation on ellislab, although it doesnt tackle much on the create_links function. Is there any parameter i can pass to it to make it write on segment(4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the base url of pagination accomodate your character :

```
$character = $this->uri->segment(3);
$config['base_url'] = base_url(). 'index.php/KitchenGuruAdminController/Admin_recipe_browse/'.$character;
```

And also change the

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

Comment: I dont know if you could still see notifications on this page. But im having troubles with my pagination. When i go to my browse page. When i click a letter of my choosing the url would be like this.

index.php/controller/function/A/$config['per_page'] here

so After clicking A, say ill limit my page for 2 entries only, so if i browse through the pagination links 1 2 3. It works fine like the above. the url should look like that.
/A/2,/A/4

But the problem lies where i dont click any letter. The url will be distorted like.

index.php/controller/function/$config['per_page'] here. when i click

Comment: Continuation.

When i click another link, it works fine like.

index.php/controller/function/ -> index.php/controller/function/2

but when i try to click another. when the 3rd segment has a number in it. the next perpage will be placed on the 4th like it treated the 3rd segment a letter.

so it would be, index.php/controller/function/2/4 so i would definitely get no records, so the previous one shown will be retained.

Another problem is that, When ever i go to default browse.

the pagination number link, will always be on page 2. It will not start on page 1

Comment: Please see this, i never noticed these errors before. I would this to be as flawless as possible. im currently working on it.